# One piece from a pizza and one piece from a cake

Tags: grammatical-number

There are one piece from a pizza and one piece from a cake. Could it be called “there are two parts” without phrase “from different dishes of food”?

Comment: "Two parts" would be assumed to mean parts of the same thing, unless specified otherwise. "I ate a slice of pizza and a slice of cake."

Comment: What do you **actually** want to say.  I'm willing to bet that it doesn't involve pizza.  Do you have a real problem or is this a made-up example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say

> There's one slice/piece of each.

Or something like what Kate said in the comments.

We usually don't use "parts" that way when it comes to food (unless you are talking about portions of ingredients in a recipe).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any possible purpose of describing "a slice of pizza and a slice of cake" as "two parts".

> Is there anything to eat in the fridge
>
> Yes. There are two parts.

It is grammatically correct, but it totally fails to communicate anything of any use.

If, for example, there was a plate of steak and potatoes, and a plate of fish and chips you could usefully say

> There are two meals.

Or

> There are two dishes.